# How to sort an arraylist of hotel rooms

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, lambda

I have an arraylist of hotel rooms 
Each hotel room has:

```
public class HotelRoom {
   int Number
   String roomType (Triple, family, double)
   String priceModel (perunit, per person,)
   Int Price 
   Int MaxGuests 
}
```

I need to return a list of the cheapest options for 
a booking of 9 people 
(Could be 2 family rooms / 3 triple rooms / 4 double, 1 single)

How could I do this?

Comment: Any code provided? Have you begun it?

Comment: can you give examples and improve your description?

Answer (score -1):

A quick solution is to loop through the current list using a for each statement and add them to a new list using an if statement that checks the price